# Retrieve last row/object in Core Data entity as a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, nsfetchrequest

I need to develop a simple `login` system for my Questionnaire app.

I have two `Entity`'s - one for saving Questionnaire data called `NGLS` which stores client details, survey answers, etc, and another called `Admin` for the user. The user can type in their `username` which gets saved to the `Admin` entity. They can then run through the Questionnaire as many times as they like, and each completed survey gets saved to the `NGLS` entity after every survey like so:

```
    // Save managedObject
    NSError *error;
    [[self.managedObjectNGLS managedObjectContext] save:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectNGLS);
    NSLog(@"Data saved");
```

There is an `export` button which uses a `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve all data stored in the `NGLS` entity, and uses the `CHCSV Parser` to write that data to a .csv which is then attached to an email.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NGLS"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // CHCSVParser
    NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc]initToMemory];
    CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc]initWithOutputStream:stream
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         delimiter:','];

    // Fetch objects to write to .csv
    for (Model *results in fetchedObjects) {
        [writer writeLineOfFields:@[results.username,
                                    results.dateStamp,
                                    ...,
```

What I need to do is retrieve the last stored `username` in the `Admin` entity and save it to the `username` key in my `NGLS` entity upon each completed survey. This will essentially allow a user to open the app and "log in" once, complete the questionnaire multiple times, and each row in the .csv will have that `username` - eliminating the need for them to type in a `username` upon every completed survey.

I have tried to fetch the `lastObject` in the `Admin` entity by using this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Admin" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"Last username is %@", [fetchedObjects lastObject]);
```

But the output is:

```
Last username is <NSManagedObject: 0xb7a20d0> (entity: Admin; id: 0xb7a1410 <x-coredata://1D073AF9-3FFB-476A-A6CC-BC15398F4B86/Admin/p2> ; data: <fault>)
```

Can anyone help me achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated. If you can think of an easier way to "log in", I'll gladly take suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: Admin *model =  [fetchedObjects lastObject]; NSLog(@"Last username is %@", model.username);

Comment: You're a star, that is perfect! Your code allows me to check what the last stored object is in the Admin entity, then I can use that to set the username key on my NGLS entity at the end of each survey. Thanks a lot mate, if you want to post your code as an answer then I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Admin *model = [fetchedObjects lastObject]; NSLog(@"Last username is %@", model.username);
```