# Single fetchRequest for multiple entities - use relationships and/or entity inheritance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, nsfetchrequest

I have a simple app which uses `Core Data`. As the user progresses through each `ViewController`, the `managedObject` gets passed through each view then saved to the store on completion. At the minute my `Model` has a single `Entity` with over `100 properties`, which I would now like to separate into multiple entities. I am fairly new to iOS programming and not overly confident with database work, so apologies if my terminology is not correct.

An example of how my app works: On my `ClientViewController`, I declare `managedObjectNGLS` which currently stores all attributes.

```
// Identify the app delegate
NGLSAppDelegate *appDelegate = (NGLSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// Use appDelegate object to identify managed object context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

// Create new managed object using the NGLS entity description
NSManagedObject *ManagedObjectNGLS;
ManagedObjectNGLS = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NGLS"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

// Declare managed object
self.managedObjectNGLS = ManagedObjectNGLS;
```

This gets passed through to `ServicesViewController`.

```
    // Allocate & initialise ServicesViewController
    ServicesViewController *services = [[ServicesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ServicesViewController"
                                                                            bundle:nil];

    // Pass managedObject to view
    services.managedObjectNGLS = self.managedObjectNGLS;

    // Push next view
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:services animated:YES];
```

Once the user has selected the desired services, the `managedObjectNGLS` gets stored to my `Model`.

```
[[self.managedObjectNGLS managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

In the `AdminViewController`, the user can export the entire contents of the `NGLS entity` using a `fetchRequest`. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100679/use-chcsvparser-to-write-data-on-single-csv-line-from-multiple-coredata-entitie) on how I am achieving this (apologies if this seems like a duplicate post, but I am still trying to understand all of this).

My question: I would very much like someone to explain the best solution regarding my entity situation. I have tried to set a `Parent Entity` which seems to work fine when only two entities are involved, but when more are introduced I get lost. I am not sure about `relationships` or an `abstract entity`?

Ideally I would like to have separate entities for `NGLS` (holds various important attributes like date stamp), `Admin` (username, site location, etc), `Client`, `Employer` (possibly separated further into Employer1,...,Employer10 eventually), and `Services`. I am not sure whether to create an `Abstract` or `Parent` entity with no attributes, then just hold relationships to that with the separate entities?

I have laid out what I would expect the entities to look like in the editor, but I am unsure if this is correct. The idea of the app is to store details about one Client per time, so on that basis the Client can have many Employers and many Services. I have implemented an extremely simple "login" system where the `lastObject` in my `Admin` entity gets stored in the `NGLS` entity (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890926/retrieve-last-row-object-in-core-data-entity-as-a-string) for a description), so the Admin entity doesn't necessarily have a relationship with anything (I may be wrong here?).

[image: Data model]

I have tried the following code but it just crashes the app:

```
NSMutableArray *entityArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *entitySuffix in @[@"NGLS", @"Client", @"Services", @"Employer"]) {
    NSString *entitySelect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entitySuffix];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entitySelect];
    [entityArray addObjectsFromArray:
     [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];
}


// CHCSVParser
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc]initToMemory];
CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc]initWithOutputStream:stream
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     delimiter:','];

// Fetch objects to write to .csv
for (Model *results in entityArray) {
    [writer writeLineOfFields:@[results.site,
                                results.username,
                                results.dateStamp,

                                results.clientTitle,
                                results.clientForename,
                                // results from different entities
```

Again, I apologise for this post as it seems like I am asking for an outright answer, but I really just need someone to point me in the right direction on how to set up separate entities and use a single `fetchRequest` to fetch data from the entire `Model` with all of it's entities. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, for that, but every answer would be a tutorial. Please get some additional information about Core Data.

Comment: Not the type of comment I was hoping for, but I agree I need to learn more about Core Data. All I am asking is a rough guide on how to set this up. I can store data to each separate `entity` with no problem. I just need to know how to use a single `fetchRequest` to fetch all data at once from every `entity` in my `Model`. Thanks for the comment, but I'm going to leave this question up in the hope someone can spend 10 minutes to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should not need to fetch all data from all entities.

Comment: If you click the link to my other post regarding the export process, you can see I need to fetch all data so I can export it from the device in the form of a .csv file (using CHCSVParser). So yes, in this scenario, I do need to fetch all data from all entities. The first row of the .csv should include all data from Services, Employers and NGLS entity relating to the particular client. If you have links to documentation or any suggestions relating to my original question, feel free to share them.

Comment: I have updated the title for better understanding, and also a snippet of code I have tried. Maybe that will shed some light and help you understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: I understood your Q. Do you know that you can access related objects (i. e. from result to client) without fetching?

Comment: I wasn't aware that possible, could you possibly post an example so I can see what you mean? Sorry if it's annoying you, I have been trying many things but can't get anything working. Im going to have another look tomorrow, but any example code you have would greatly help me out!

Comment: Your model is really weird, that is why I wrote that you need an introduction. But I will try it. If you have a result entity referring a client, which has a name attribute, it is simply `
result.client.name`

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but after some preliminary research I agree that I need to completely restructure my `data model`. I haven't had time to properly look into this yet as the product needs to be ready for deployment soon. I will deploy a working version with one `entity` (containing `100+ properties`) for now, then push another version with extensive `model` updates. Thanks for your patience with me and I appreciate your help!